# LIKE ignores magic Unicode character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unicode, sql-like

SQL Server 2008 R2

```
 create table #test (c1 nvarchar(5) not null)

  insert into #test values 
  (N'aaa'),
  (nchar(65533)),
  (N'bbb')

  select * from #test where c1 like N'%�%'
  select * from #test where c1 like N'%'+nchar(65533)+N'%'
```

Result is

```
c1
----
aaa
�
bbb
```

Why? I haven't found in MSDN any notes on this case.

Comment: I have check it with sql fiddle everything is fine;http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fde76/3

Comment: It might be your `collation` what is your `tempdb` database collation?

Comment: Alsin, if you are interested, I just updated my answer to be clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That character (and many others, depending on the Collation version being used) just happens to have no sort weight defined. It is effectively nothing. So whether you have 1 instance of it or 100, it is invisible to anything but binary Collations. Meaning, the following `WHERE` predicates:

```
LIKE N'%' +  NCHAR(0xFFFD) + N'%'

LIKE N'%' +  NCHAR(0xFFFD) +  NCHAR(0xFFFD) + N'%'

LIKE N'%' +  NCHAR(0xFFFD) +  NCHAR(0xFFFD) +  NCHAR(0xFFFD) + N'%'
```

and so on, are all equivalent to the following:

```
LIKE N'%%'
```

And that is why you get all 3 rows returned.

This does not mean that this character *should* have no sort weight. It actually is defined in Unicode as having a weight, but for some reason Microsoft has left quite a few characters without any sort weight at all (though the total number of characters missing a sort weight is decreasing with each new Collation version, the newest being the version `140` Collations, which came with SQL Server 2017 and are only for the Japanese Collations).

For any character that has no sort weight, the only way to match it is by using a binary Collation. Binary Collations are those ending in either `_BIN` or `_BIN2`, but only use the `_BIN2` Collations since they sort properly whereas the older `_BIN` Collations do not. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM #test WHERE c1 LIKE N'%�%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2;
```

Returns:

> c1
>   ----
>   �

Also, I tested with the following and they returned all 3 rows:

- Latin1_General_CS_AS_KS_WS
- Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_KS_WS_SC

So, the following should be good:

- Latin1_General_BIN2
- Latin1_General_100_BIN2

Also, it is best to use the highest Collation version available for the Collation you are trying to use. For example, use `Latin1_General_100_*` instead of `Latin1_General_*`, and so on. Use the following query to find the Collations available on your Instance:

```sql
SELECT col.*
FROM   sys.fn_helpcollations() col
ORDER BY col.[name];
```